# Copy the characters from the array

Tags: c, arrays

im' trying to write a program to prescribe the contents of the array to replace special characters (enter, tab) their counterparts in ASCII code. The problem occurs when an incorrect declaration array s:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void escape(char [], char []);

int main()
{
    int k,j;
    k=j=0;
    char s[]="klks\nsgs \t";
    while(s[k]!=EOF)
        k++;
    char t[k];
    escape(s, t);
    while(j!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%d", t[j]);
        j++;
    }
}

void escape(char s[], char t[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i!=EOF;i++)
    {
        switch(s[i])
        {
        case '\n':
            t[i]="\\";
            i++;
            t[i]="n";
            break;
        case '\t':
            t[i]="\\";
            i++;
            t[i]="t";
            break;
        default:
            t[i]=s[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm kinda doubting you're going to find an EOF in that 0-terminated string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues I was able to find:

1. You're testing for `EOF` instead of `'\0'` to find the end of the string.
2. You're not allocating enough space for the `t` array. Right now, it's the same length as the `s` array, but you need it to be longer to accommodate the additional escape characters.
3. You're assigning a string (e.g. `"\\"` or `"n"`) to a `char` in `escape`. Use `'\\'` or `'n'` instead.
4. You're use the same index for `s` and `t` in escape, resulting in you skipping characters in `s` whenever you escape a character. You need to track the current index of `s` and `t` separately.
5. You're using a `for` loop that checks `i` against `EOF` in `escape`. You should be using a `while` loop that checks `s[i]` against `'\0'`.
6. You never terminate the string `t`.

**Too many errors... Aborting...**

Comment: @Kulis If you're escaping the string `"Hello\n"`, that string has six characters, since `'\n'` is just one character. If you replace the `'\n'` with a `'\'` and a `'n'`, that's two characters. The escaped string therefore has seven characters, which is longer than the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Looping over a string until is done until `NULL` and not `EOF`.

I can't really understand what the question is, could you please clearify?

Comment: Yes. unless your string is, for some strange reason, terminated by (char)EOF then you should probably check for '\0' or just 0. Also you are not terminating the string "t". You need a t[i] = '\0' after the loop. Finally, I also don't understand the question you are asking.